# Serialize bools to XML differently

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm using the `XmlSerializer` to serialize a class to XML. The class contains a few boolean properties, that are serialized like so:

```
public bool Boolean1;
public bool Boolean2;

<Boolean1>true</Boolean1>
<Boolean2>false</Boolean2>
```

I want the generated XML to look like this:

```
<Boolean1/>
```

That is, true booleans will appear as an empty tag, and false booleans will not appear at all. I could add a `ShouldSerializeX` method to both booleans to make the element disappear in case the boolean is false, but how do I just leave the tag name with no content if the element is true?

Also, isn't there some sort of `[XmlIgnoreIfNull]` or `[XmlIgnoreIfDefault]` attribute that would render most `ShouldSerialize` methods redundant?

Comment: You're having to then imply a value based on node existence... What if somebody sends some badly formed XML that doesn't have the node, you go "oh well, it's false" and actually that's the wrong answer. Not sure if it would matter to you, but having true or false explicitly in there for me would be more comfortable.

Comment: Actually, since false is the default value, I'm just going to have to imply the default value if the node doesn't appear, and imply 'true' if it does appear. It's done all the time with nullable types, where you don't want null nodes to appear at all.